# How do I make my button play a sound?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, audio

I know that this has been asked many, many times before, but how do I make my button play a sound when it's pressed?

this is my button's code:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/c1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />
```

and here is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.appname;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

what do I have to add to make my button play a sound? If it helps I'm using Eclipse.

**EDIT**

I don't really know what I'm doing when it comes to this, so if you could please show me what to add to my code that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **OnClickListener**. 
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) is the developer section detailing how to do it.
You need to implement the **onClick method** once you assign the OnClickListener to your button.
 [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) is the section about buttons, the code here will get you started.
For playing the sound, I recommend a [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) You can set your MediaPlayer to start (playing) in the onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to understand events generated by views in android ,in your case button click event, you have to use [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

and youre code look like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnPlaySound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c1);  
    btnPlaySound.setOnclickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.view_id:
             break;
          default:
            break;
         }
   }

}
```

Comment: Using the Activity as OnClickListener will increase complexity and readability of the code as soon as you get 2 buttons (i.e. with 2 listeners)

Comment: @ben75 while having two button i have update my answer and setting onClick listener om individual button its create anonymous class for every button so i am using this way and my code will clean and clear